# Java list files in URL directory?

Tags: java, url, webserver

Is this possible? Can I make a folder on my webserver named /gamelevels/ with .gamelevel extension, point a URL there and retrive all the .gamelevel files from there? Nothing like this seems to exist in java (googling/SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some servers are configured to provide an HTML listing of contents when the URL of a directory is provided.  If the server supplies that list, the client can parse the list for the contents.

*It is considered a **security hole** for a server to provide that listing.*

Comment: It is just an issue of making our game as practical as possible and adding the ability to download new levels (very little time to be creative to create levels and artwork, most of it spent coding). I trust we will think about security at some point, if for no other reason than to learn.

Comment: *"the ability to download new levels"*  Deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can not unly install/update the game as needed, but you can declare new levels as a 'lazy' download and they will be automatically downloaded when needed.  Very easy for the end user.