# How to get list of files from URL

Tags: java

I have an URL http ://......../somefolder/ I want to get the names of all the files inside this folder. I have tried this below code but it's showing error.

```
URL url = new URL("http://.............../pages/");
       File f=new File(url.getFile());
       String list[]=f.list();
       for(String x:list)
       {
           System.out.println(x);
       }
```

Error :-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Directory.main(Directory.java:25)

Comment: Aaaaand where is `Directory.java:25` ? Apart of that I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754707/java-list-files-in-url-directory

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me.  There are cases where you want to get a list of files that are part of your project and, for example, your project is a web app that is deployed as a war.  Using File to get a directory and then listing the contents will work while you are developing the app locally and the project exists as files in directories but will fail when the application is deployed as a war file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it like this.

HTTP has no concept of a "folder". The thing you see when you open that URL is just another web page, which happens to have a bunch of links to other pages. It's not special in any way as far as HTTP is concerned (and therefore HTTP clients, like the one built into Java).

That's not to say it's completely impossible. You might be able to get the file list another way.

Edit: The reason your code doesn't work is that it does something completely nonsensical. `url.getFile()` will return something like `"/......./pages/"`, and then you pass that into the `File` constructor - which gives you a `File` representing the path `/....../pages/` (or `C:\......\pages\` on Windows). `f.list()` sees that that path doesn't exist on your computer, and returns null. There is no way to get a `File` that points to a URL, just like there's no way to get an `int` with the value 5.11.